# html requested resource not available for servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web

I am trying to connect html to a servlet to get the user input but I get an error that says The requested resource is not available. I even put the servlet on the same folder as the html file, but the error keeps coming. I have the servlet both in Java resources and in html folder (web content). It should be visible. Below is my code for html file and servlet.
html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!--This is the login page.-->
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login Page</title>
<style>
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
    backroung-repeat: repeat-1 ; 
}

h1 {
    color: maroon;
    margin-left: 40px;
} 
</style>
</head>
<body background="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gray-user-management/512/login-512.png" >
<h1>Autentification</h1>
<form action="ConnectionMaker" method="post">
User name:<Input type="text" name="user"><br/><br/>
Password:<Input type="password" name="pass"><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

<a href="autentification.jsp">login</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ConnectionMaker
 */
@WebServlet("/DBConnection")

public class ConnectionMaker extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ConnectionMaker() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
         String user = request.getParameter("user");
            String pass= request.getParameter("pass");
            System.out.println(user+" "+pass);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `<form action="ConnectionMaker" method="post">` to `<form action="DBConnection" method="post">` or maybe `/DBConnection` (with slash). You hit the URL, not the class name.

Also, why call `doGet` inside `doPost`?

Comment: doGet was there by default. I didn't have the chance to remove it.